# OracleSequenceMaxValueIncrementer in a loop performance improvement suggestions

Tags: java, database, spring

I have a loop in which i get the incrementer value and use it.
As far as the performance is concerned, due to the incrementer i feel, the process takes a lot of time when the loop is for alot of customers.
I timed it without the incrementer with just a dumm value and that naturally was alot faster. 
Aprrox 10 times faster.

How can i improve performance with the incrementer in place?

The following operation gets called in the loop

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
public String getNextReferenceNumber() {
    return this.ibs2BankDirDebRefNumSequenceGenerator.nextStringValue();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a way to improve the performance of the incrementer.  It inherently involves a Java <-> Oracle Database round trip.

If you are going to improve the performance, you need to be able to get a block of reference numbers in one go; i.e. with one database round-trip.  In essence, you need to be able to increment the native Oracle `sequence` by `N` .... and then dole out the values as reference numbers on the Java side.